# How do I use facebook's 'Force Pop Ups' method in my html file?

Tags: html, facebook, browser, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is how the facebook developers site explains the use of 'Force PopUps'.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ .

But when i copied the same code and saved it as an html file, the code didn't work. I tried to call
`FB.ui({ method: 'feed',message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});`
as an onclick event, still it didn't work. Anyone please provide a solution (with a sample code pls) . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/force-popups

your code line looks like its missing some of the must-have fields. also dont forget to load the JS-SDK after the body. (preferred as async call)

include this after the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rufinus. i copied the same entire thing on ma html file. And may i please know how to load js-sdk . I am tired.. fed up..or watever of googling. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Even that didn't work. Ma code is actually very simple. Since i cant place the code here as a comment. I ve placed ma code sample in a new question. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894892/why-fb-ui-does-not-work-even-after-loading-javascript-sdk". Please respond. Thanks.